# wahy change created at format in laravel api resource?

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

i defined created at format in baseModel like this:

```
protected function serializeDate(DateTimeInterface $date): string
{
    return Carbon::instance($date)->toIso8601String();
}
```

but when i use api Resource, changed created_at format

this is api resource:

```
 public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'last_status' => $this->lastStatus->status,
        'terminal' => [
            'provider' => $this->terminal_provider,
            'psp' => $this->terminal_psp,
        ],
        'account' => [
            'iban' => $this->account_iban,
        ],
        'count' => $this->count,
        'amount_settle' => $this->amount_settle,
        'amount_wage' => $this->amount_settle,
        'created_at' => $this->created_at,
        'statuses' => AggregateStatusResource::collection($this->whenLoaded('statuses')),
        'shaparak_files' => ShaparakFileResource::collection($this->whenLoaded('shaparakFiles')),
    ];
}
```

whay change format for all of api resources

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using? And ? Please edit your question and show us how are you're calling `toArray`.

Comment: Did the below post answer your question?

Comment: yes, but 'setToStringFormat' is deprecated. is there any alternative?

Answer (score 1):

The `created_at` date in your `Resource` class is not getting converted using `toIso8601String` because it's not longer using the model's `toArray()` method which will call `serializeDate()`.

One option would be to update your `Resource` to explicitly format the `created_at` date:

```
'created_at' => $this->created_at->toIso8601String(),
```